# Can we read ServiceBehavior attribute from client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to read the ServiceBehavior attribute of WCF service at the client end. How can I do that?

-
Ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense. Network boundaries separate the client and the server and what the client sees is what the server exposes. For example if you are using SOAP (basicHttpBinding) all that the client knows about this server is the WSDL. It doesn't even know that this server is WCF so talking about `ServiceBehavior` in a client is wrong (the server could even be written in some other language, not even .NET).

Now if this service behavior sends some information downstream to the client (for example some custom HTTP header) then the client could read and access this information, but that will depend on the specific scenario.